# How does the writing speed correlate with the generation of LTO drives and tape?

Tags: backup, speed, tape, lto

How does the writing speed correlate with the generation of LTO drives and tape?

For example: 
Can you write with an LTO-6 drive with the same speed on LTO-6 and LTO-5 tapes?

Data is written in linear serpents to the LTO tape [[wikipedia:LTO]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Tape-Open#Core_technology).
How many rewinds are needed to write a full LTO-x tape? Does it require one (slow) direction change per **wrap**?

Answer (score 2):

LTO6 drive will not write LTO5 tape as fast as it would write LTO6 tape , all things being equal (same dataset).
The drive uses dynamic speed matching , so fixes the tape speed , and so data rate, according to the speed of the data going through the host interface.
Since LTO6 has a higher recording density than LTO5 , then at the same physical speed through the drive , you would write LTO6 media faster than LTO5 media.
How many wraps (change of direction) does it take to write a full tape ? - this is dependent on the particular LTO drive/media and you can find this out when drive/media specification is defined as 'tracks'

Comment: To create a paragraph you need to add two blank lines. It could help to make your part about the wraps more prominent.